# custom base directory for wordpress installation with docker

Tags: wordpress, image, docker

I am using https://docs.docker.com/samples/wordpress/ (slightly modified) to setup a wordpress installation with docker. Everything works, I am only missing one custom option:

The wordpress installation goes into `/var/www/html` and I would like to change it to something like `/var/www/{mysitename}/public_html` - is this somehow possible with volume settings or something else?

I do find some articles about it, but either I do not get it or it's wrong context.

Thx!

Comment: Why do you want to change the path?

Comment: 1) just to play around 2) having my .env file outside of the public_html folder

Answer (score 0):

With `working_dir: /var/www/{mysitename}/public_html` I was able to change directory, but still one folder **wp-content** goes into the old directory.

Comment: I got the same issue. I was able to setup wordpress in a custom directory, but wp-content with 3 empty subdirectories appear in the default directory.